# UIButton position while UIImage zoom on UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a scenario where I need to implement an Offline Map concept for which I am using the image of map on a `UIScrollView` that zooms on PinchGesture, which works fine.

**Problem**

I have a `UIButton` on map. While zooming, the button does not track its position with respect to `UIImageView` which is being scaled.I am able to reframe the button without affecting its size. But the position is wrong.

**TLDR**,
I need to reproduce the **mapView with annotation kinda concept** on `UIScrollView` with `UIImage` on it. Can any one help?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is the UIButton added on the UIImageView?

Comment: @IronMan: Its over imageView but inside scrollView in hierarchy

Comment: @Meera Did you get the solution, I too facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer for this. I initially stored the button value in a CGRect initialButtonFrame. Then I updated the button frame (only origins, not the size of the button size as I wanted the button not to zoom like the image ie; I button should not zoom) using the scrollview delegate

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{
   [self manageImageOnScrollView];//here i managed the image's coordinates and zoom
   [self manageButtonCoordinatesWithRespectToImageWithScale:scale];
}

-(void)manageButtonCoordinatesWithRespectToImageWithScale:(float)scaleFactor
{

//initialButtonFrame is frame of button 
   self.button.frame = CGRectMake((initialButtonFrame.origin.x * scaleFactor),
                                  (initialButtonFrame.origin.y * scaleFactor),
                                           initialButtonFrame.size.width,
                                           initialButtonFrame.size.height);

   [self.scrollView addSubview:self.button];// I removed the button from superview while zooming and later added with updated button coordinates which I got here
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.. When i try to apply the scale to button's origin.. Origin shoot to higher value depending upon the speed of pinch. Going out of bounds of the visible screen. :(

Comment: Are you calculating the scale factor properly?

Comment: Got figured it out, had to do some math and some debug, phhewww.. :) Thanks for responding, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your current offset and zoom of your map, you should be able to compute the position of your button:

```
//Assuming your map image has its origin at 0, 0
CGPoint mapOffsetX, mapOffsetY; // these would come from your map as you calculated it.
CGPoint mapZoomFactor; // 1.0 means not zoomed, 3.0 means zooming in 3x, etc
CGPoint buttonAnchorPosition; //the position of your button on your map at 1.0 zoom

CGFloat buttonX = buttonAnchorPosition.x * mapZoomFactor + mapOffsetX;
CGFloat buttonY = buttonAnchorPosition.y * mapZoomFactor + mapOffsetY;

CGPoint buttonPosition = CGPointMake(buttonX, buttonY);

button.position = buttonPosition;
```

Try that, good luck

Comment: :Thank you. But how to calculate mapOffsetX,mapOffsetY?

Comment: the offset can't be found from map cause i am not using a map. I am using scrollview and image with a button on it.

Comment: How do I calculate mapOffsetX, mapOffsetY and mapZoomFactor